# gcc and g++ cannot be found in cygwin from eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin

I am a software engineering student in my first year. I used to work on a program called eclipse with using java for developers and "cygwin" compiler. Everything was working perfectly but I accidentally uninstalled the cygwin. I re-downloaded it a few days ago but now when I work on eclipse and try to run the program it says *"gcc" path not found*, *g++ path not found*, and *make path not found*. What can I do to solve this problem?

I tried asking around but no use.

Comment: Did you installed your c++ cygwin compiler as well? Also, please write Software in the right way, not soft wear...

Comment: yes i did ..... sorry didn't pay attention to that i will next time thx for letting me know